# Using CSS to display copy editing marks

Tags: html, css

I fairly new using CSS and I am trying mimic the content of a display poster. Basically, I am looking for a way to add copy editing marks on a web page. See the image below.

[image: Screenshot of desired result]

Is there a way using CSS to display the "NOT" and red arrow?

I'm really not sure where to start so I don't have any code to show. I've been searching this forum and others with no results yet.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: There are a few ways to go about this, but one would be to make NOT and arrow an image, and then wrap certain words in spans and place the image accordingly using `:after`

Comment: @HunterTurner is right. Wrap those words in some spans, and then use some :before and :after element.

Comment: Maybe you can do it with popper.js and a little bit of css

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using the `::before` and `::after` css pseudo classes on a span tag.

I have added a quick example below.

```css
* {
    font-family: arial;
}

.fancyNot {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.fancyNot::before, .fancyNot::after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    color: #f06559;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.fancyNot::before {
    content: "NOT";
    top: -1em;
    left: -1em;
    transform: rotate(-5deg);
}

.fancyNot::after {
    content: "^";
    bottom: -0.7em;
    left: -0.1em;
}
```

```html
<p>Lunch will <span class='fancyNot'>&nbsp;</span> be served at</p>
<p>Silent Auscion will <span class='fancyNot'>&nbsp;</span> close at</p>
<p>Our Guest Speaker will <span class='fancyNot'>&nbsp;</span> speak at</p>
```